# Getting all instances of a regular expression in python with

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all the link innerHTML's using the following

```
import re

s = '<div><a href="page1.html" title="page1">Go to 1</a>, <a href="page2.html" title="page2">Go to page 2</a><a href="page3.html" title="page3">Go to page 3</a>, <a href="page4.html" title="page4">Go to page 4</a></div>'
match = re.findall(r'<a.*>(.*)</a>', s)

for string in match:
    print(string)
```

But I'm only getting the last occurrence, "Go to page 4"
I think it's seeing one big string and several matching regex's within, which are treated as over-lapping and ignored. So, how do I get a collection that matches

['Go to page 1', 'Go to page 2', 'Go to page 3', 'Go to page 4']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that regexp's are greedy, that is they will attempt to consume the longest string possible. So you're correct that it's finding up until the last `</a>` it can. Change it to be non-greedy (`.*?`):

```
match = re.findall(r'<a.*?>(.*?)</a>', s)
                             ^
```

However, this is a horrible way of parsing HTML and is not robust, and will break on the smallest of changes.

Here's a far better way of doing it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '<div><a href="page1.html" title="page1">Go to 1</a>, <a href="page2.html" title="page2">Go to page 2</a><a href="page3.html" title="page3">Go to page 3</a>, <a href="page4.html" title="page4">Go to page 4</a></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
print [el.string for el in soup('a')]
# [u'Go to 1', u'Go to page 2', u'Go to page 3', u'Go to page 4']
```

Then, you can use the power of that to also get the href as well as the text, eg:

```
print [[el.string, el['href'] ]for el in soup('a', href=True)]
# [[u'Go to 1', 'page1.html'], [u'Go to page 2', 'page2.html'], [u'Go to page 3', 'page3.html'], [u'Go to page 4', 'page4.html']]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really quite understand ? in regexs, this was a great learning experience. Here's what I got to work

match = re.findall(r'<a.*?>(.*?)</a>', s)

Comment: @user1450120 I didn't see the other .* :) Anyway - expect this to break later on or potentially return wrong results... Look at using `beautifulsoup` to parse HTML - it's easy to learn and flexible

Comment: What kind of input might cause this to break?

Comment: @user1450120 Try `<   a> <img src="</a> something" /> <</a >` for eg:

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid parsing HTML using regex at **ALL** costs. Check out [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) as per why. But to sum it up...

> Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp

Instead I would take a look at a python HTML parsing package like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [pyquery](https://github.com/gawel/pyquery/). They provide nice interfaces to traverse, retrieve, and edit HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using lxml:

```
from lxml import etree

s = 'some html'
tree = etree.fromstring(s)
for ele in tree.iter('*'):
    #do something
```

It provides iterParse function for large file process, also takes in file-like object like urllib2.request object. I have been using this for a long time for parsing html and xml.

See: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class